# How do you Reset the Windows Updates Software List When There is a Superius Update Which Has Been Already Installed

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-11, windows-update

I am using Windows 11 and my update list shows:

[image: Pending Updates]

When I type:

```
Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate
Import-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate
Get-WindowsUpdate
Download-WindowsUpdate
Install-WindowsUpdate
```

I get:

```
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
>>
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate
>>
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsUpdate
>>
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Download-WindowsUpdate
>>
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-WindowsUpdate
>>
(base) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

In this case there are no updates. If there are updates when running a command like `Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -AutoReboot` they get installed. But these are not shown when running Windows Update GUI as in the screen shot above. It only shows `Realtek - Extension - 6.0.9250.1`.

I believe `Download error 0x80248007` is because the driver is already installed previously. The update History shows a similar update.

[image: Update History]

With `Get-WUHistory | Select-Object -First 20`

```
ComputerName Operationname  Result     Date                Title
------------ -------------  ------     ----                -----
LAPTOP-OT... Installation   Succeeded  07/08/2023 06:26... Realtek - Camera - 10.0.22000.20199
```

PowerShell displays this one item and it gets struck. This is an update which was installed when I ran `Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -AutoReboot` last. But previous updates with the Windows Update GUI are not show. The command hangs after displaying the 1st and only update using PowerShell.

When I run `wushowhide.diagcab` with automatic repair to hide this `Realtek - Extension - 6.0.9250.1` update I get no updates to hide.

How do I get rid of this superius update from the Windows Update GUI? As it is, windows update GUI do not show any new updates. Is there anything else I need to do to make my fully system functional again?

Other thing I have tried is:

1. Clearing the Windows Distribution folder
2. Removing all the RealTek media drivers using `PnPUtil`
3. Windows Update trouble shooter (System > Troubleshoot > Other trouble-shooters > Windows Update)
4. `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` and `SFC /scannow`

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooter for Windows Update (*Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters*) ?

Comment: I have tried that too.

Comment: Try a Windows 11 Repair Install and use the option to Keep Everything. See if that works.

Comment: 1. What is a Superius update? 2. If you wish, you can completely reset all updates using SFC and DISM -- but that prevents rolling back, i.e., removing updates: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase` See https://lazyadmin.nl/it/dism-command/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The superius update is `Realtek - Extension - 6.0.9250.1` as it gives `Download error 0x80248007`. I believe this error (`0x80248007`) is raised when windows tries to install an already installed update, hence the the update `Realtek - Extension - 6.0.9250.1` is not needed. Perhaps this is the same driver as `Realtek Semiconductor Corp - Extension - 6.0.9250.1` which is successfully installed before (shown in update history).